# ChatBot in swift 3.0

Tags: swift, chatbot, aiml

So I wanna know how i can include a ChatBot in my swift program.

- Would i have to write the code in swift or is there a way i can include the Artificial Intelligence Markup Language (AIML) in my program?
- What kind of data do i have to include in a ChatBot that, for example, helps high school students with physics?
- In what format is this data stored (in arrays, variables, files, etc.)?
- How can i customise my ChatBot for the needs of each individual user?

This would definitely be my first ChatBot so please explain elaborately.

Comment: https://github.com/BotLibre/BotLibre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Develop a chat boot it's not as easy as it seems.

Have you consider develop a Message extension? Using your app in a "chat" environment should help users to interact with your bot in a natural way.

You can use Machine Learning to adjust your bot responses to each individual user in their own devices (If it's not a server based bot)

The data that your bot needs will be specified by your project, so you will have to do a good research about users needs

I'm sure that this O'Reilly [book](http://www.oreilly.com/design/free/design-for-voice-interfaces.csp) will hell you as well as this Smashing Maganize [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/conversational-design-essentials-tips-for-building-a-chatbot/).